# Mapping numeric value in OpenHab2 to String

Tags: homekit, openhab, ios-homekit

I added Homematic HM-CC-RT-DN thermostats by connecting a CCU2 to OpenHab2.
Then I defined the thermostats as items for HomeKit to use:

```
Group gBedroomThermostat "Bedroom Thermostat" [ "Thermostat" ]
Number BedroomThermostatCurrentTemp "Bedroom Thermostat Current Temperature" (gBedroomThermostat) [ "CurrentTemperature" ] { channel="homematic:HM-CC-RT-DN:xxx:yyy:4#ACTUAL_TEMPERATURE" }
Number BedroomThermostatTargetTemperature "Bedroom Thermostat Target Temperature" (gBedroomThermostat) [ "TargetTemperature" ] { channel="homematic:HM-CC-RT-DN:xxx:yyy:4#SET_TEMPERATURE" }
String BedroomThermostatHeatingCoolingMode "Bedroom Thermostat Heating/Cooling Mode" (gBedroomThermostat) [ "homekit:HeatingCoolingMode" ]
```

This all works fine, except for the last line in this definition. The thermostats only supply a percentage value of the valve state (`homematic:HM-CC-RT-DN:xxx:yyy:4#VALVE_STATE`). What I would like to do is to map this percentage value to the String `'Off'` if the valve state is 0% and to `'On'` otherwise.

I looked into OpenHab2 Transformations (https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Transformations) but I'm neither sure how to use them in this case, nor where to apply them.